# Dynamically set Identity Start With in DB2

Tags: db2

I would like to be able to do something like this to dynamically set the identity START WITH value. Is it possible?

```
CREATE VARIABLE v_number BIGINT DEFAULT 142;
ALTER TABLE txn
  ALTER COLUMN id SET DATA TYPE BIGINT NOT NULL 
     PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE 
     GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (
       START WITH v_number * 1000000, INCREMENT BY 1
     );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDL statements usually require literal values, so you'd need to use dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE VARIABLE v_number BIGINT DEFAULT 142;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE txn ' ||
  'ALTER COLUMN id SET DATA TYPE BIGINT NOT NULL' || 
     'PRIMARY KEY ' || 
     'GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (' ||
       'START WITH ' || v_number || '* 1000000 INCREMENT BY 1 )';
```

There's no reason to declare both `UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY KEY` constraints - the primary key values are unique by definition.